# Block relation with specific domain in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, malware

I am facing an issue of redirect and the cause is a js file being load from 3rd party domain name.

the script is added to almost 50% of my JavaScript that includes a Javascript file in header of my wordpress the JavaScript file is located in "sarcoma[dot]space/js/main.min.js".

I want to block the domain so my wordpress shouldn't get any input from that file/domain. How I can do this.

"My website got hacked 2 months after the installation of Malcare plugin"

I've removed the plugin and deleted its all files and change the rules did everything but I can't change those 50% JavaScript files.

I've cleaned the website but the 50% JS files are still infected.

Comment: Hi, you can do it with a firewall; anyway, your question is a little off topic here. Please see the description of [wordpress tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress/info)